# Collection View, get the content of the cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a Collection View with the segue in the storyboard from the cell to the SecondViewController. It works well, when I click to any cell it goes to the next screen.

Now I try to get the text that is clicked in that cell and send it to the next cell. I could do that in a table view, so I adapt from that. I leave conmented the part that has the problem:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var secondScene = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
    //let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()//it gets the row in a table
    //let indexPath = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath()//I try to adapt to a Collection View. It does not work
    secondScene.selected2 = textArray[indexPath!.row] 
}
```

Comment: [`indexPathsForSelectedItems`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/indexPathsForSelectedItems)?

Comment: It says "cannot invoke indexPathsForSelectedItems with no arguments"

Comment: You have to invoke it on `self.collectionView` of course!?

Comment: let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()